# Get index for value NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I've got a value like so: `@"2329300"` and I've got a `NSDictionary` like so :`{@"John Appleseed":[@"2329300",@"2342322",@"32i249"]}`

How do I find the index of the key/value pair in the `NSDictionary` when I've only got a string value of the entire list that's known as the value. I'm assuming there's no duplicates in the dict.

I know that there's `indexForObject` on a `NSArray` but is there a similar thing for a dict?

I imagine it would look something like this:

```
[NSDictionary indexForValue:value]; // returns index number.
```

And even then the `NSString` doesn't match the value, so I'd need a workaround for that too.

Comment: Because Dictionaries are not ordered there is no index.

Comment: Yep, no such thing as the "index" of a dictionary entry.

Comment: What do you suggest I use then?

Comment: We-work the question clearly explaining what you want, what you have tried along with examples. Perhaps what you want is the index of the item in the list of number strings? Or the key of the dictionary entry that contains what you are searching for?

Comment: Do note that what you have above is an NSDictionary containing one entry whose key is "John Appleseed" and whose value is an NSArray containing 3 entries.  You'd access the first array element as `myDict[@"John Appleseed"][0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding. Dictionaries are unordered collections. They do not have any particular order for their key/value pairs. You can't have indexes to the key/value pairs because that implies a fixed order.

Think of a dictionary as a bunch of kids milling around on a playground. You can call out a kid's name "Johnny, come here!" and fetch that kid (use a key to find an object) but what does order mean for kids that won't sit still?

You can create an array of the keys from a dictionary and sort that into a particular order (an alphabetical list of the kids on the playground) if that's what you want, or you can create an array of dictionaries, or an array of a custom data object that contains any arbitrary properties that you want.

### EDIT:

For a table view, an array of dictionaries is probably a good choice. Each entry in the array contains a dictionary with all the settings for a cell in the dictionary. If you have a sectioned table view then you want an outer array for sections, containing inner arrays for the rows, and each entry in the inner array containing a dictionary.

I tend to prefer custom data objects to dictionaries though. (An object that just has properties for each setting I want.) That way the list of values and their types is crystal-clear and fairly self-documenting.

Comment: Hmm seems legit. Only thing is that in some cases I'd prefer to use a dict instead. I'm making a tableview with contacts displayed inside it, and a dict makes sure "name":"number" never corrupt. Using two Arrays and linking the indexes gives a higher chance of such corruption.

Comment: Like I said, use an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary will contain the values to describe one entry (name:Bobby, number:800-555-1212)